# SQL Server Connection String

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, sql-server-2008-r2

OK, total noob question here.  I'm toying around with Silverlight, and need to connect to a database.  When I connect in server explorer (VS 2010) it works fine, because it's using my windows account to authenticate.  However, when I start debugging the server side stuff is running on a different account (NT-SERVICE or something to that effect) which has no privileges on the SQL server.  I've tried embedding my username/password like this:

`connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog={DATABASE};Integrated Security=True;User={DOMAIN}\{USERNAME};Password={redacted}"`

but it doesn't seem to be working.  I keep getting an error:

`The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.`

Thanks for helping,

Eric

Comment: Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Comment: No luck.  I tried it with Integrated Security = False, True, and SSPI, and no luck.  I'm beginning to wonder if it's something to do with my service, not the connection.

Comment: Looks like it's actually an unrelated problem.  I guess I need to study up a bit more on wcf for the moment.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't forget to post the solution on here... in case someone else runs into a similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I wasn't adding DataContracts to my Linq-to-Sql classes.  From the linq-to-sql designer, set serialization to Unidirectional.  Turns out it was completely unrelated to connection strings.  Sigh...

Answer (score 2):

Try **User Id=**, not **User=**

```
  connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog={DATABASE};Integrated Security=True;User Id={DOMAIN}\{USERNAME};Password={redacted}"
```

http://www.connectionstrings.com/